# Routing Mesh stop working in docker swarm

Tags: docker, udp, docker-swarm, checksum

I have problem with my swarm cluster

I have created plain service which is listening on specific port (ie. 8080)
from the beginning everything works fine
but after several days I have problem with connection using routing mesh
lets say my cluster is

```
192.168.1.100 - manager0
192.168.1.101 - manager1
192.168.1.102 - manager2
192.168.1.110 - worker0
192.168.1.111 - worker1
192.168.1.112 - worker2
```

when I connect to node `192.168.1.110` via ssh and then I use curl command not all nodes respond (but they work, and have up status)
behavior looks like this:

```
curl -v 192.168.1.100:8080 - OK 
curl -v 192.168.1.101:8080 - NOK
curl -v 192.168.1.102:8080 - NOK 
curl -v 192.168.1.110:8080 - NOK 
curl -v 192.168.1.111:8080 - NOK
curl -v 192.168.1.112:8080 - OK
```

We can get similar behavior when you disable 4789 udp port

From docker docs:

`UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic (container ingress networking).`

but in my cluster I have opened this port and the real problem is bad checksum
while I perform

`tcpdump host 192.168.1.100 and 'port 4789' -i eth0 -vvvv`
then I recieved the result

```
12:11:06.149126 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41970, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 110)
    test1234.39679 > 192.168.1.100.vxlan: [bad udp cksum 0x6eb2 -> 0xceb2!] VXLAN, flags [I] (0x08), vni 4096
```

`bad udp cksum 0x6eb2 -> 0xceb2!`

When I disable checking the checksum the connection back to normal and everything works fine (command below)

`ethtool -K <interface> off`

The re-initialization of docker swarm cluster wont help.

Any advice how to debug it or resolve it? (without disabling sum check?)

Comment: meeting same cksum problem and not fixed even if I execute `ethtool -K <interface> tx off`command:(

Comment: @Libraco you can try to upgrade your network driver.
when you initialize docker swarm which network interface do you indicate? if eth0 you should also invoke `ethtool -K eth0 tx off`, my little misunderstanding was this command is disabled sum check, but now I know this command move calculating sum check from the network card to the processor.